# PostBackUrl is not working just postback on same page

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to make use of the `postbackurl` property. But when I click the button, the page just seems to post back to itself.

My code is :

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCheckOut" runat="server" Width="100px" CssClass="btn1"  
     Text="CHECKOUT" PostBackUrl="~/CheckOut.aspx" CausesValidation="true"  
     OnClientClick="return CartAmtValidate()" ValidationGroup="qty" />
```

Comment: It might be possible that your javascript function return false and prevent page to postback.

Comment: @SainPradeep OP says the page is posting back to itself.  If the javascript function was returning false it would prevent any postback.

Comment: my javascript function returns true.

Comment: are the pages located in the same directory?

Comment: Did you resolve it eventually? I have the same issue and no JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `OnClientClick` like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCheckOut" runat="server" Width="100px" CssClass="btn1" Text="CHECKOUT"
  PostBackUrl="~/CheckOut.aspx" CausesValidation="true"  
  OnClientClick="if(!CartAmtValidate()) return false;" ValidationGroup="qty" />
```

if your `CartAmtValidate` function returns true you will be able to go to `CheckOut.aspx` page absolutely.
Hope this can fix your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Property should be make on the server side and server side control. You are using onClientClick which is the javascript property for the asp.net button control.

Comment: Can u elaborate how to work with onclientclick and postbackurl?